# Safari scroll bar on mobile gets in way of sticky header

Tags: ios, mobile, header, sticky

I made a webpage with a sticky header that works fine on a desktop but not so well on mobile. For example, on an iPhone, if you turn your phone on to landscape mode, safari's tool bar will cover my sticky header. Similarly opening a link to my page on instagram will result in the same issue (instagram header will cover mine).

Heres's the HTML

```
<div id="container">



<div id="infotab-mobile">
<div id=rosemenu>
<div id="rose">
<img class="inforose" id= "roseimg" src="images/rose.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#infotab-mobile{
display: initial;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
}

#rosemenu{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;
display: inline-block;
}

#rose{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(232, 232, 232, 0.96);
padding-top: 2%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
}

#roseimg{
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 display: -webkit-box;
}
```

I've also noticed that using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; disables an ios feature that allows you to scroll to the top of a web page by taping the safari tool bar. Has anyone discovered any work arounds?